# How to keep values in <select> after submitting a form in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, filter, form-submit, laravel-filters

I have multiple `<select>` by city filter
[image]

`select` in blade

```
<select id="city" multiple name="city[]">
    @foreach($cities as $city)
        <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Query for `select`

```
if ($request->has('industry')) {
    $businessesQuery->whereIn('industry_id', $request->input('industry'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
            @if(request('type') != "")
            $('#city').find('option[value="' + "{{request('type')}}" + '"]').attr('selected', true);
            @endif
```

little manage according to your code then its should work

Comment: what I should write instead of 'type'